# Binding map from config yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

In spring boot project i am trying to bind a map from yaml file. I have tried most of the solutions to bind map but getting following error:

```
    Property: order.events
    Value: null
    Reason: must not be empty
 Action:
 Update your application's configuration
```

As you can see on config class i have getter/setter through lombok and inner class is a static class.

```
@Data
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "order", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class OrderConfig {

    private String clientKey;
    private String apiVersion;
    private String endpoint;

    @Valid
    @NotEmpty
    private Map<String, Event> events;

    @Data
    public static class Event {

        @NotBlank
        private String action;
        @NotBlank
        private String eventName;
    }
}
```

By using lombok i already have all necessary getter and setter methods. My config yaml file is:

```
    order:
      clientKey: client_1
      apiVersion: 1.0.0
      endpoint: https://www.ordertest.com/api
      events:
        order.create:
          action: track
          eventName: purchase
        order.place:
          action: track
          eventName: purchase
```

And my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OrderConfig.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode them in double quotes with square brackets [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding)

> When binding to Map properties, if the key contains anything other than lowercase alpha-numeric characters or -, you need to use the bracket notation so that the original value is preserved. If the key is not surrounded by [], any characters that are not alpha-numeric or - are removed.

```
order:
  clientKey: client_1
  apiVersion: 1.0.0
  endpoint: https://www.ordertest.com/api
  events:
    "[order.create]":
      action: track
      eventName: purchase
    "[order.place]":
      action: track
      eventName: purchase
```

And also you need to annotate `@Configuration` on `OrderConfig` class

> Sometimes, classes annotated with @ConfigurationProperties might not be suitable for scanning, for example, if you’re developing your own auto-configuration. In these cases, you can specify the list of types to process on any @Configuration class

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your keys to be `order.create` and `order.place` then you have to specify them as `"[order.create]"` and `"[order.place]"` in order to escape the periods. Otherwise you should be able to work with just `create` and `place`.

Comment: i have tried both your advice to escape and key without periods but both didnt help.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figured why i had that problem and wanted to give a shot with the latest Spring boot version 2.2.0 which they introduced ConstructorBinding.

I have changed my config class to following version and its fixed.

```
@Data
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "order", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class OrderConfig {

    private final String clientKey;
    private final String apiVersion;
    private final String endpoint;

    @Valid
    @NotEmpty
    private final Map<String, Event> events;

    @Data
    @ConstructorBinding
    public static class Event {

        @NotBlank
        private final String action;
        @NotBlank
        private final String eventName;
    }
}
```